# Memory issues in-memory dataframe. Best approach to write output?

Tags: r, output, text-files

I’m running into memory issues in my R script processing huge folder.  I have to perform several operations per file and then output one row per file into my results data frame.

sometimes the resulting data frame has hundred of rows pasted together In one row as if it got stuck in the same line (seems that rbind is not working ok when the load is huge) 
I think the issues arises when keeping a temporal data frame in memory to append results, so I’m taking other approach: 
 A loop to read every file one by one, process it, and then open a connection to results file, write a line, close the connection and go to read next file. Came to mind that avoiding a big df in memory and writing immediately to file could solve my issues.

I assume this is very inefficient, so my question:   is there another way of efficiently appending line by line of output  instead of binding in-memory data frame and writing to disk at the end?

I’m versed in the many options: sink, cat, write line......my doubt is which one to use to avoid conflicts and be the most efficient given the conditions

Comment: Perhaps share some of your current code? I don't think you should be doing rbind everytime but first collect everything in a list? "hundred of rows" should not be an issue. Instead of doing sink/cat/write for each file also you could do so for every 1.000.000 files or so for efficiency? Integers/booleans vectors take less space than numeric/double.

Comment: Seriously need some sort of minimal code example to see what you have already tried. It would be nice to know what you are doing to each file, and how big each file is. If you can't make a minimally reproducible example, you at least need to give us enough to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: At a minimum an example of an input or two and an expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Instead of offering a bounty, you'll get better results if you follow @AdamSampson's advice and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to explain what you're trying to do and where the problem(s) occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using the following snippet:

```
library(data.table)
filepaths <- list.files(dir)
resultFilename <- "/path/to/resultFile.txt"
for (i in 1:length(filepaths)) {
  content <- fread(filepaths, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
  ### some manipulation for the content 
  results <- content[1]
  fwrite(results, resultFilename, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, append = TRUE)
}
finalData <- fread(resultFilename, header = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

In my use case, for ~2000 files and tens of millions of rows the processing time decreased over 95 % compared with read.csv and incrementally increasing data into a data.frame in the loop. As you can see in https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/importing-data.html section 4.3.1 and https://www.r-bloggers.com/fast-csv-writing-for-r/, `fread` and `fwrite` are very affordable data I/O functions.

Comment: Maybe you mean, `library(data.table)`. `fread()` is a function as you correctly use it and afaik not a package,...